# What method would you go through to find an $n$ such that $\phi(n)=100$?

Tags: number-theory

So, clearly, 101 is a solution.

But $n=125$ is also a solution, so is 250.  How would one come to that solution without knowing these values beforehand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a start.  Write $n$ as a product of prime powers, $n=p^\alpha q^\beta\cdots$ with $\alpha,\beta,\ldots>0$.  Then we want
$$p^{\alpha-1}(p-1)q^{\beta-1}(q-1)\cdots=100\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Note that the term $p^{\alpha-1}$ might not "really" be there, because $\alpha$ might be $1$; but the term $p-1$ **must** be there.  So what it comes down to is:

> every prime factor of $n$ must be $1$ more than a factor of $100$.

This gives the possibilities
$$p=2,\,3,\,5,\,11,\,101\,.$$
From now on it's trial and error, but you should not find it's too hard.  An example of the sort of thing to think about: if $p=11$ then $\alpha$ must be $1$, otherwise in $(*)$ the LHS is a multiple of $11$ and the RHS isn't.

Comment: I like this. This is exactly my train of thought, but for you to write it out like that really solidifies how to go about doing this. Number theory seems to be a lot of "out of the box" thinking.

Comment: I'm surprised there are no hard and fast formulas for the $\phi$ function.  All though, a formula would require a formula first to find the primes...